# How to call a JS function on HTML page loaded inside OBJECT Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I am loading a HTML page inside an  tag, Since iPAD not supporting iFrame i am using the  tag to load External html pages inside a container. Everything works fine, Now i want to call a function from a Loaded Page (Page which loaded inside ). Can any one help me to find out the solution ?

```
"<object id='page' width='100%' height='100%' data='"+pageURL+"' style='position:absolute;'></object>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i GOT the Solution for accessing the Javascript function of HTML page loaded inside Object Tag.

```
window.objectID.functionName();
```

This will call the function ("But it is not working in IE8"). Use iframe for IE.

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome, either. Can you post a working example?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want your code to call a JavaScript function in the context of the loaded page, you can't if the pages aren't from the same origin (which from the sound of it, they aren't). It's prohibited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The JavaScript code in your page can't interact with the other page.

If the pages are from the same origin, the `object` element's [`contentWindow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-object-element.html#dom-object-contentwindow) and [`contentDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-object-element.html#dom-object-contentdocument) properties are supposed to provide access to it, although I haven't used them on `object` elements and don't know how well-supported they are.

Comment: Thankyou So much Crowder, Both the files are from same domain only. I will try to access using contentWindow or contentDocument. and let you know the result

Comment: Hi Crowder,  i have tried the following code and found it is not working.  Here is the code  inline `<SCRIPT>  function getFunction(){  var objWind = document.getElementById("myObj");  objWind.contentWindow.loadedPageFunction();  objWind.contentDocument.loadedPageFunction();  }  </SCRIPT>  <BODY>  <OBJECT id="myObj" width="800" height="700" data="page.html"></OBJECT>  <input type="button" value="callFunction" onClick="getFunction()"></input>  </BODY>`    #CODE in the Loading PAGE#.  `<SCRIPT>  function loadedPageFunction(){  alert("Loaded PAge Function Called");  }  </SCRIPT>`

Comment: Finally i GOT the Solution for accessing the Javascript function of HTML page loaded inside Object Tag.  `window.objectID.functionName();`  This will deal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query parameter:

```
<object type="text/html" data="html/page.html?param=1"></object>
```

Then, inside `page.html`, use JavaScript to check the query parameter. If the query parameter is properly set, call the function you want to call.