# <div> collides with <object>

Tags: javascript, svg, html-object

I'm currently working on a website with a custom-cursor. *(A div chained to the mouse-position.)*

I know want to implement an SVG-file into this project, **but I can't move the custom-cursor over the SVG.**

What's going on and how can I fix this?

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    cursor.style.top = e.y + "px";
    cursor.style.left = e.x + "px";
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;

    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#testObject {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>

I can't hover over the object below. (The cursor get's stuck on the edge.)<br><br>
<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/SVG_example_markup_grid.svg/2560px-SVG_example_markup_grid.svg.png" type="image/svg+xml" id="testObject"></object>
```

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_Reiter/e8j4oy3d/29/)

---

*Note: As you can see in my code-snippet, I'm using `<object>` to implement the SVG. I know that using `<img>` would solve my problem, but I have to use `<object>`, because I have a script that reaches inside of the SVG-file and then adds an EventListener('mouseenter') to a shape with a specific id. – As far as I know, that's only possible with `<object>`, so I have to find a solution that works with `<object>`.*

### Update:

I did some more testing and found out that the: **window.addEventListener('mousemove'…** is actually not triggering, when hovering over the **object**.

Comment: "(A div chained to the mouse-position.)" <-- You don't need to do that. You can use custom cursors directly: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/

Comment: @Dai Thank's for the input! But, in my case, I do actually need this. – The custom-cursor from my snippet is a simplified version of the actual cursor, that I'm working with. – The actual cursor consists more then one element and has a bunch of stuff built into it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562356/how-to-call-a-js-function-on-html-page-loaded-inside-object-tag
might be useful for you

Comment: This is not a problem in Firefox except that the cursor is actually showing when not hovering either `<p>` or `<object>`. Strange.

Comment: @chrwahl Wow, I just check it out in Firefox, you're right, this is behaving in a very unexpected manner…

Comment: Can't you use inline svg with `<svg>` instead of an object?

Comment: @Daantje I will try this out now and I will then add the results of my test to the OP, Thank You!

Comment: Don't use `<object>` tag, rather use the SVG directly inside HTML. This way you can interact with it, styling it via CSS and adding event listeners in JS.

Comment: @Daantje / @cloned – **Yeah, this totally worked.** Thank you guys, so much! :) – Does anyone wanna post an official answer, suggesting that I should loose the `<object>` and just work with `<svg>`? – That way someone gets the reward.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: Disable the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the `<object>` so the event is passed to the document below, and thus is captured by the `mousemove`:

```css
#testObject {
  ...
  pointer-events: none;
  ...
}
```

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    cursor.style.top = e.y + "px";
    cursor.style.left = e.x + "px";
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;

    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#testObject {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>

I <strike>can't</strike> CAN hover over the object below.<br><br>
<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/SVG_example_markup_grid.svg/2560px-SVG_example_markup_grid.svg.png" type="image/svg+xml" id="testObject"></object>
```

Comment: Thank You, Very Much, for your answer! But unfortunately I can't use this. – Here's the thing: Inside of my actual SVG, there's a shape with a certain `id` and I wrote a script that adds an EventListener('mouseenter') to this shape. That, of course, stops working, when I add `pointer-events: none;` to the object…

Comment: Any idea, on how I could still get this to work?

Comment: So there's a whole other point to the question? Please add **all the details** to the OP.

Comment: Sorry, will do now. *Update: Done.*